# I am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
   SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of 
   class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
```

I've goggled my problem but all were giving the same solution to add the hibernate jars in the webapp libraries in the build path which I have done in the first place. Still it is not solved. I have tried different versions of jars. But the problem persists.

please find the webapp library screen shot here

[WebApp library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6LH0.jpg)

Adding the updated Deployment Assembly

[Updated Deployment Assembly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O25Pf.jpg)

Comment: what build tool are  you using?

Comment: I am not using any. I am using Eclipse IDE. Server - Tomcat

Comment: if it is `dynamic web project then `Right click the project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path` then In the list at left side click on Deployment Assembly. Click "Add" button. Select "Java Build Path Entries" and click next. Now select your hibernate jar files or library. Click finish. click Ok

Comment: After selecting the Java Build Path Entries I am not finding any jars or libraries

Comment: on left side there is option of `deployment assembley`??

Comment: Yes I have selected Deployment Assembly and then selected Add. There after selecting the Java Build Path Entries and clicking next there are no jars/libraries

Comment: after selecting `add` click to `java build path entries`

Comment: can you please show me `deployment assembly`
till then, try using `http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhibernate353jar.htm`

Comment: @HarneetSingh I have added the screen shot of my Deployment Assembly. Please have a look

Comment: you need to click add and then select entries from java build path select all click ok, restart application its done

Comment: please [SEE] (https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FQ19bw.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F20718566%2Fmaven-dependencies-not-being-added-to-web-inf-lib&docid=tYgTNfXIJEZ2MM&tbnid=xT2p-Ax3R_smSM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwikk9uy6a3VAhWMvY8KHQlQAVMQMwgkKAIwAg..i&w=971&h=625&bih=873&biw=1745&q=deployment%20assembly%20eclipse%20with%20lib&ved=0ahUKEwikk9uy6a3VAhWMvY8KHQlQAVMQMwgkKAIwAg&iact=mrc&uact=8)
here you will get what you need(add lib) for that you need to click on add and choose the maven

Comment: @HarneetSingh I am not using Maven. I have downloaded the jars and added to the buildpath. I also tried to add them to the deployment assembly. Still the problem persists

Comment: @kailashnath: then please update your deployment assembly pic,
till then see [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/Dougclectica/resource/BLOGS_UPLOADED_IMAGES/EclipseUserLibrariesDeployment.png)

Comment: @HarneetSingh added the same.

Comment: @kailashnath: can you please try [This](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhibernate353jar.htm) jar, as per my previous comment :)
add thsi jar and just to check if that works

Comment: @HarneetSingh Thank you for the solution. I have added the jar mentioned and it required another version of Hibernate-core. Added that and now its working.

Comment: Can you please add [This](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhibernate353jar.htm) jar and that will work.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `hibernate` dependencies, you can find it below:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: I am not using any build tool. I am just using Eclipse IDE and running the application on tomcat

Comment: then you have download jar files manually. put jar files into WEB-INF>lib folder and add into builtpath, Go to project properties > java  built path > libraries > add external jar  files

Comment: I already have jar files added. I have attached the screen shot of my build path. Please have a look.